# Microsoft Teams GraphAPI Missing SetStatusMessage

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Quite recently Microsoft introduced a new version GraphAPI which provides the functionality to set a user status message:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setstatusmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I am using the latest nuget packages of the required nuget packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.3" />    
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.34.0" />
```

Regarding to [Microsoft's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setstatusmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), there should me a method/property `SetStatusMessage` followed by `PostAsync(requestBody)` like:

```
await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].Presence.SetStatusMessage.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

But there isn't (also couldn't find an extension method somewhere):
[image: Missing Method]

I did find the method, when using the `Me` property of the client:

[image: SetPresence method]

I am pretty new to MS GraphAPI so chances that I am missing obvious are pretty high.

Comment: I'm referencing Graph SDK 5.34 and both methods are there: `await graphServiceClient.Users[""].Presence.SetStatusMessage.PostAsync();` and `await graphServiceClient.Me.Presence.SetStatusMessage.PostAsync();` Maybe some issue with referencing the correct version of the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The rather unsatisfactory solution to the problem: Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work on [my internet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qi40Oc):

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Presence.SetStatusMessage;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var serviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);
    
        var request = serviceClient.Users["abc"].Presence.SetStatusMessage.ToPostRequestInformation(
            new SetStatusMessagePostRequestBody
            {
                StatusMessage = new PresenceStatusMessage
                {
                    Message = new ItemBody
                    {
                        Content = "Hello World"
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Instead of *.ToPostRequestInformation()* you can also do an

```
var response = await ...PostAsync()
```

depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the "solution", that I mentioned in my answer was simply: reboot. I guess some nuget packages were not loaded propably or there was a conflict with another version (my guess)